# How to multiply a vector by an array/matrix element-wise in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, elementwise-operations

I have a multidimensional array `a` whose shape is (32,3,5,5) and an array `v` with a shape of (32,). How could I multiply (i,3,5,5) with (i,) for each i using numpy other than a for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `a` and `v` as the two arrays, few approaches could be suggested -

```
a*v[:,None,None,None]
a*v.reshape(-1, *[1]*3)
(a.T * v).T
np.einsum('i...,i->i...', a, v)
```

Comment: I tried the first approach you posted. It works! Thanks.